# Angular ng-repeat mixed with jquery radio button and select default value using checked attribute

Tags: jquery, angularjs, radio-button, angularjs-ng-repeat, radio-group

I created a codepen to describe my problem:

http://codepen.io/kk20994/pen/ygvQQO

HTML

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController" class="container">
  <form class="form row">
    <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="radio in radioGroups">
      <label for="{{radio.id}}">{{radio.label}}</label>

      <div class="radio">
        <label>
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios_{{radio.id}}" id="optionsRadios_default" value="" checked>
    Not Sure
  </label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio" ng-repeat="value in radio.values">
        <label>
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios_{{radio.id}}" id="optionsRadios_{{radio.id}}_{{value.key}}" value="{{value.key}}">
    {{value.label}}
  </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
angular.module("app", [])
.controller('MainController', function($scope){
  $scope.radioGroups = [{
    id: 1,
    label: "Is this fissible in rural area?",
    values: [{
      key: "true",
      label: "True"
    },{
      key: "false",
      label: "False"
    }]
  },{
    id: 2,
    label: "Is this for all students of district?",
    values: [{
      key: "true",
      label: "True"
    },{
      key: "false",
      label: "False"
    }]
  }];
});
```

Output:

[image]

So even though the two radio button groups have different ids and names, still it don't work. Even if I check the DOM the property of first radio button is "checked" is false.

Note I can't change the DOM but I want to make default value checked for all radio button without jquery after render of DOM.

Answer (score 0):

In order to select a radio button in `angular js` you need to use the `ng-model` property inside `ng-repeat`. I have placed an additional field `value` inside `$scope.radioGroups` to set the value of the radio button.

Also there is no need to use `value="{{value.key}}"` instead you can use `ng-value="value.key"`

For the first radio button with Not Sure selection you cannot use `ng-value` since the value does not contain any expression. You can directly initialize it as `value=""`

Here is the working code attached.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular.module("app", [])
            .controller('MainController', function ($scope) {
                $scope.radioGroups = [
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        label: "Is this fissible in rural area?",
                        values: [{ key: "true", label: "True"}, 
                                 { key: "false", label: "False"}
                                ],
                        value: ""
                    }, 
                    {
                        id: 2,
                        label: "Is this for all students of district?",
                        values: [{ key: "true", label: "True"},
                                 { key: "false", label: "False" }
                                ],
                        value: ""
                    }];
            });
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController" class="container">
        <form class="form row">
            <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="radio in radioGroups">
                <label for="{{radio.id}}">{{radio.label}}</label>

                <div class="radio">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios_{{radio.id}}" ng-model="radio.value" id="optionsRadios_default" value=""> Not Sure
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="radio" ng-repeat="value in radio.values">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios_{{radio.id}}" ng-model="radio.value" id="optionsRadios_{{radio.id}}_{{value.key}}" ng-value="value.key"> {{value.label}}
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Since `value: ""` set for all objects in the scope variable, Not Sure will be selected by default. You can change its value according to your need to change the selection.